# meaning of ?: in regular expression used for checking in php

Tags: php, regex

```
<?php
if (!preg_match("{(?:login|logout|register)\.php$}", $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]))
{    
    if (empty($_SESSION["id"]))
    {
        redirect("login.php");
    }

 }
?>
```

Couldn't understand how my 1st if conditions is checking pages other than login.php, logout.php, register.php .. What ?: is doing?

Comment: See http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html

Comment: This kind of duplicate is admittedly almost impossible to find, but please do try to look through some sort of documentation first.

Comment: @deceze very easy if you check this [reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean) :)

Comment: @HamZa Try finding *that* one when searching for "?:". :)

Comment: @deceze Try this [query](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=[regex]%20%22%3f%3a%22) :D (but I get your point)

Answer (score 0):

?: is a [non capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) ie, it matches the expression but do not capture it.

> Non-capturing parentheses group the regex so you can apply regex
>   operators, but do not capture anything.

For example:

If I dont want to capture the protocol like `http` then see i will use the below regex

```
(?:http|ftp)://([^/\r\n]+)(/[^\r\n]*)?
```

Now, my result looks like this:

```
Match "http://google.com/"
     Group 1: "google.com"
     Group 2: "/"

Match "http://google.com/ABCD/XYZ/PQR"
     Group 1: "google.com"
     Group 2: "/ABCD/XYZ/PQR"
```